# Regex editor application for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, regex

I'm working with regular expressions on Mac and I'm using:

http://reggyapp.com/

But it does not show the exact matches numbered. I'm looking for other applications. Something similar to regex widget:

http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/regexwidget.html

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[Patterns](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/patterns-the-regex-app/id429449079?mt=12) doesn't seem to number the individual matches either, but it does support replacing text and multiple regex implementations.

[image]

Comment: Have you used it? Is it useful?

Comment: @DanielBeck I did buy it, but still prefer to use TextMate or throwaway scripts most of the time.